# In PhpStorm new file menu, there is no .php or php class option

Tags: phpstorm

In PhpStorm, when i want to create a new file, there used to be three options for php at the top of the list. new PHP file, new PHP Class, and something else.

Now there is no option for php. there is just 'file', 'directory', 'new scratch file' and then html/css/etc file types.

Comment: Screenshots please. Also describe from where do you invoke that menu (what area is active).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved. for anyone having this question in the future, you should know that PhpStorm has the above behavior when indexing the project, which usually happens every time you open a project.

but in my case, something(I don't know what), had caused to add "." to the list of paths to be indexed, making PhpStorm index the whole home folder, and naturally, it took a lot of time.